# How to pick the nearest marker from clicked point in vispy?

Tags: python, simulation, vispy

In [vispy](http://vispy.org/) library I have a list of points shown as markers, and I want to change the color of(or just get the index of) the point which is nearest to the clicked point.

I can get the pixels of the clicked point by event.pos, but i need its actual co-ordinate to compare it with others (or get pixel point of other markers to compare it with the event location).

I have this code to get the nearest point index.which takes input of an array and a point(clicked one)

```py
def get_nearest_index(pos,p0):
    count=0
    col =[(1,1,1,0.5) for i in pos]
    dist= math.inf
    ind=0
    for i in range(len(pos)):
        d = (pos[i][0]-p0[0])**2+(pos[i][1]-p0[1])**2
        if d<dist:
            ind=i
            dist=d
    return ind
```

But the problem is i have to pass both of them in same co-ordinate system.
Printing out `event.pos` returns pixels like: `[319 313]` while my positions, in `pos` array are:

```
[[-0.23801816  0.55117583 -0.56644607]
 [-0.91117247 -2.28957391 -1.3636486 ]
 [-1.81229627  0.50565064 -0.06175591]
 [-1.79744952  0.48388072 -0.00389405]
 [ 0.33729051 -0.4087148   0.57522977]]
```

So I need to convert one of them to another. Transformation like

```
tf = view.scene.transform
p0 = tf.map(pixel_pt)
print(str(pixel_pt) + "--->"+str(p0))
```

prints out `[285 140   0   1]--->[ 4.44178173e+04 -1.60156369e+04  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]` which is nowhere near the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When transforming the pixels to your local co-ordinates, you are using transform.map, which according to the [vispy tutorial](http://vispy.org/visuals.html), gives you map co-ordinates. What you need to use is the inverse map.

You could try doing this:

```
tf = view.scene.transform
point = tf.imap(event.pos)
print(str(event.pos) + "--->"+str(point))
```

Likewise, in case you need to transform specific sets of markers, this would be a better approach.

```
ct = markers.node_transform(markers.root_node)
point = ct.imap(event.pos)
```

Comment: `markers.node_transform(markers.root_node)` and `view.scene.transform`  both works same for now, and i can get the nearest poitn. On a side note ` print([int(x) for x in tf.map(p)])` for each p in pos prints negative points like `[-1746, -342, 0, 1]` so map & imap aren't exactly opposite?

Comment: Pixels out of range from visible canvas are denoted as negative or extremely large pixel points depending on their location. So, that is probably what you are getting.